# Android Change a variable in service from other app

Tags: android, service

the title says all, I need to change the variable of my service from a activity in my other app , what to finalize the service or not, this is possible?

I found the Message object , but I do not quite understand

Comment: use broadcasting concept of android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to implement a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Your Service listens for the Broadcast and the other App sends the Broadcast.

Example Reciever:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get bundle from intent and use it to set your Variable in your Service
  }
}
```

Example Broadcaster ([courtesy of Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("de.vogella.android.mybroadcast");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you , this work for me , and this link also helped me:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm